# VW Bora (1.9 L TDI) - Misfire on cylinder 2

Tags: vw, diesel, misfire, bora

It starts every time and the engine shakes badly in higher gears. However, if I turn the engine on and off MANY times it will eventually kick back in and run as it should. So frustrating.

Any suggestions on a fix please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which fuel does it use?

Comment: its a diesel, 1.9 SE TDI

Comment: FYI, Bora is what was sold in the US as the mk4 Jetta ('99.5-'05).

Comment: Do you have a [glow plug symbol](http://dashboardsymbols.com/2011/08/glow-plug-indicator-symbol/) lit up on your dash? Does this shaking happen only when the engine is cold, or does it happen regardless of engine temperature

Comment: No warning lights whatsoever and it happens whenever the car has been sat for an hour or so. start it up and chugs away. not affected by the temperature at all.

Comment: In that case I believe the issue is related to fuel delivery. Assuming the problem is affecting just Cyl #2, I'd have the injector for that cylinder checked out.

Comment: thank you. yeah trying to avoid expensive work at all costs so trying easy fixes first.

Comment: Did you get it sorted out? Do you know what the codes were?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [my comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26253/my-vw-bora-has-a-misfire-on-cylinder-2#comment41346_26253):

It looks like the issue is with fuel delivery, specifically fuel delivery to Cylinder #2. Here is what I would check:

- ***confirm that the Cyl #2 injector is receiving signal to rule out an electrical issue***

  This will involve unplugging the injector connector and testing the ECU-side connector for voltage.

  As this is a diesel, it isn't very accessible - the valve cover will have to come off. [This video](https://youtu.be/gaOGBPKD2oI) should help.

If this were a petrol engine, I'd also be worried about a clogged injector. However, it looks like diesel injectors are [not as prone to clogging](http://www.racq.com.au/cars-and-driving/cars/owning-and-maintaining-a-car/car-maintenance/diesel-injector-cleaning), so I'll leave it to someone with diesel experience to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, the VW diesels are notorious for loading up the intake with soot, which must be cleaned out. I would imagine a repair shop or dealership would be familiar with the procedure. The alternative would be to simply replace the intake, but I would hazard a guess that getting the old one cleaned might be cheaper (new intake manifolds are currently ~USD300). If you want to try to tackle this yourself, [there's a guide on-line](http://www.myturbodiesel.com/wiki/intake-manifold-removal-cleaning-of-carbon-build-up-mk4-tdi-engine/).

Comment: cheers, thanks for the pointer. will have a look now.

Comment: But would this explain the intermittency of the problem?

Comment: @Zaid: Not sure, but the EGR valve is part of what gets coked up, so it could be sticking and maybe the engine shudder from repeated start attempts shakes it enough to loosen up a bit and work properly. That's just conjecture, but I do know that the carbon build-up is a known problem.

Comment: so how about the injection harness? could this be the issue? that it needs replacing?